# JavaScript - best way of handling 'this' pointer and custom arguments

Tags: javascript, this, bind

I have a function where I create a button and add an EventListener to it. There is a confusion in handling 'this' pointer and the button inside the event listener function.

```
Sample.prototype.myfunc = function my_func() {
  this.attra = someValue;
  this.attrb = somValueb;

  tmpDelNode = this.doc.createElement('span');
  tmpDelNode.innerHTML = '<span class="del">X</span>';
  this.newAttachmentContainer.appendChild(tmpDelNode.firstChild);
  delbtn = this.doc.querySelector('.del');

   delbtn.addEventListener('click', function deleteNewAttachment(delbtn) {
      delbtn = this.doc.querySelector('.del');
      delbtn.previousElementSibling.remove();
      delbtn.remove();
      this.newAttachments = null;
      }.bind(this),
  false);
}
```

In the above function, inside the addEventListener, I want to retain the 'this' pointer and still want to use the delbtn as well. I have tried to bind 'this' pointer to sample and passed the delbtn as an argument.

I want to achieve the same in more precise and best way. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Method 1**

You'll need to store your `this` in a variable before your event handler :

```
Sample.prototype.myfunc = function my_func() {
  this.attra = someValue;
  this.attrb = somValueb;

  tmpDelNode = this.doc.createElement('span');
  tmpDelNode.innerHTML = '<span class="del">X</span>';
  this.newAttachmentContainer.appendChild(tmpDelNode.firstChild);
  delbtn = this.doc.querySelector('.del');

  var that = this; //Store your this here

   delbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.previousElementSibling.remove();
      this.remove();
      that.newAttachments = null; //Use 'that' here
  },
  false);
}
```

> **Method 2**

You can use an arrow function to keep your previous context :

```
Sample.prototype.myfunc = function my_func() {
  this.attra = someValue;
  this.attrb = somValueb;

  tmpDelNode = this.doc.createElement('span');
  tmpDelNode.innerHTML = '<span class="del">X</span>';
  this.newAttachmentContainer.appendChild(tmpDelNode.firstChild);
  delbtn = this.doc.querySelector('.del');

   delbtn.addEventListener('click', () => { //Arrow function here
      delbtn.previousElementSibling.remove();
      delbtn.remove();
      this.newAttachments = null;
  },
  false);
}
```

Comment: Method 1 is more prompt. Please modify your method 1 to use 'this'pointer to point to delbtn and remove the argument.  var that = this; //Store your this here

   delbtn.addEventListener('click', function deleteNewAttachment() {
      this.previousElementSibling.remove();
      this.remove();
      that.newAttachments = null; //Use 'that' here
  },
  false); Like this. I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap your function with parenthesis and give `delbtn` as argument ([bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)) :

```
Sample.prototype.myfunc = function my_func() {
    this.attra = someValue;
    this.attrb = somValueb;

    tmpDelNode = this.doc.createElement('span');
    tmpDelNode.innerHTML = '<span class="del">X</span>';
    this.newAttachmentContainer.appendChild(tmpDelNode.firstChild);
    delbtn = this.doc.querySelector('.del');

    delbtn.addEventListener('click', (function deleteNewAttachment(delbtn) {
        delbtn.previousElementSibling.remove();
        delbtn.remove();
        this.newAttachments = null;
    }).bind(this, delbtn), false);
}
```

Or just declare your function above (it's prettier):

```
function deleteNewAttachment(delbtn) {
    delbtn.previousElementSibling.remove();
    delbtn.remove();
    this.newAttachments = null;
}

Sample.prototype.myfunc = function my_func() {
    this.attra = someValue;
    this.attrb = somValueb;

    tmpDelNode = this.doc.createElement('span');
    tmpDelNode.innerHTML = '<span class="del">X</span>';
    this.newAttachmentContainer.appendChild(tmpDelNode.firstChild);
    delbtn = this.doc.querySelector('.del');

    delbtn.addEventListener('click', deleteNewAttachment.bind(this, delbtn), false);
}
```